# Matplotlib (pylab): how to specify a substituted html colour code for plotting?

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I'm running into a problem which I suspect is related to order of substitution in the parser.

From the matplotlib docs, it has:

"For a greater range of colors, you have two options. You can specify the color using an html hex string, as in:

`color = '#eeefff'"`

I like this method because it gives me colour values that are (for me) easy to understand - and thus easy to set programmatically to colour choices that I want to achieve. So, I have a snippet of code, that, for instance, cycles between increasingly bright values of green (or at least that's what I would like it to achieve):

```
for t in range(runtime):

...

 green = 0x008000
    if t < 32:
       x_vals = [x for line in film.frames[t] for x in range(len(line)) if line[x] > 0]
       y_vals = [y for y in range(len(film.frames[t])) for x in film.frames[t][y] if x > 0]
       if len(y_vals) > 0:
          pylab.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, color=('#%x' % green), s=8, marker='s')
       green += 0x400
       if green > 0x00FF00: green = 0x00FF00
```

...except that this doesn't work. What I get is:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "#"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "#"
invalid hex color string "#"
```

As I mentioned this looks like one of those arcane order-of-substitution issues because if I type a literal

```
pylab.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, color='#008000, s=8, marker='s')
```

things seem to work.

So how do I get a substituted html colour value into the plot function? It seems as though it should be a simple matter of exactly the right syntactic form - but I've not been able to guess what that is yet.

One thing I ABSOLUTELY DO NOT!!! want to end up having to do is using the 'alternative' method of floating-point tuples, from the documentation:

> or you can pass an R , G , B tuple, where each of R , G , B are in the
>   range [0,1].

because:

1) Floating-point values are always something of an approximation, thus mapped into an integral RGB colour space there is a chance if your computations round in poor manner to get an imprecise colour - not quite the one you selected (or wished to select)

2) The hex triplet method of colour specification is at least to me quite intuitive and obvious. While it's easy enough to think about how they would map into the 0-1 colour space, I'd rather not have to resort to that method because it means a "translation" in my head - as well as in the code - you'd have to do, e.g. green = hex_green/0x100 (or indeed is that right?) Does the [0,1] space actually map as [0,1) - so that hex 255 is one less that what would map to notional float 1, or do they map 0,1 in a space mapping from 0-255 as truly 256 values over the closed range [0,1] so that 1=255 etc. etc.? So the mapping is not intuitive and in fact is somewhat ambiguous.

So unless there is really NO option but to use a triplet form if you want to use a computed substitution, if it really is the case that the low-level design of the command parser permits no option other than a text literal, if you want to use the html colour specification, I'd rather not be offered 'solutions' using such a workaround. But by all means if this is the only way it can be done at all, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: try `color='#00%x' %green`  printing the result of the substitution, and it looked like two zeros were missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be missing zeros at the start. Python removes the zeros that is not important for the numerical value.

`'{0:06x}'.format(green)` Use this to make it always pad with zeros to a length of 6 digits.

```
In [221]: '{0:x}'.format(green)
Out[221]: '8000'

In [222]: '{0:06x}'.format(green)
Out[222]: '008000'
```

`'%06.x' %green` also works if you want to use this syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I would NEVER have guessed this, nor would any of my debug efforts have found this particular quirk. It's in the category, I think, of "you'd have to know, to know".